Making memory in FPGA and how to use the SDRAM on De1-Soc board
Im working in a project with A FPGA board (De1-Soc - Cyclone V) and in project there is supposed to be an internal memory to make connection with rest of the system and read or write some data in it.
I want to use the SDRAM which is on board but the problem is The user manual pin assignment even though it says 64Mb of data is storable in it but doesn't have enough pins in it. And if I want to use it as a memory which already have some data stored in it I dont know how to it.
So the main problem is how to make the SDRAM on board as memory for my project.

The DE1-SoC Board has a 64MB (32Mx16) SDRAM connected to the FPGA.
The DE1-SoC documentation doesn't seem to specify the exact part number of the 32Mx16 SDRAM TSOP device from ISSI, but a comment from @Vlad said the part is IS42S16320D-7TL. The SDRAM datasheet shows the following address table:



Parameter
32M x 16




Configuration
8M x 16 x 4 banks


Bank Address Pins/Balls
BA0, BA1


Autoprecharge Pins/Ball
A10/AP


Row Address
8K(A0 – A12)


Column Address
1K(A0 – A9)



The DE1-SoC User Manual (rev.F/rev.G Board) has the following which shows all the address inputs on the SDRAM are connected to the FPGA:

The user manual also has section 5.5 SDRAM Test in Verilog:

DE1-SoC system CD offers another SDRAM test with its test code written in Verilog HDL. The memory size of the SDRAM bank tested is still 64MB.

So, as far as I can tell:

The DE1-SoC has connected all the address pins between the SDRAM and FPGA to use the full capacity of the SDRAM.
The DE1-SoC CD-ROM available should have an example in Verilog which tests the full 64MB of the SDRAM. Albeit the question has been tagged vhdl, but the Verilog example should help as a starting point for how to use the SDRAM.

W.r.t. the following part of the question:

he user manual pin assignment even though it says 64Mb of data is storable in it but doesn't have enough pins in it

SDRAM uses row and column addressing, where the RAS (Row Address Strobe Command) and CAS (Column Address Strobe Command) are used to strobe either the Row or Column address from the address pins. The total number of address bits is 2 (bank) +  13 (row) + 10 (column) = 25 address bits which is 32M addressable locations. Hopefully this explanation helps to explain the SDRAM addressing.

I have a DE1-SoC, and I can confirm the SDRAM part is IS42S16320D-7TL
